# Youtube embed allowfullscreen not working in TeXView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**I need to show a youtube video, as well as a description there, will have math equations. all works fine. but the problem is allowfullscreen not working in TexView. I need allowfullscreen feature. How to over come this problem?**

I used [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex#texview-image-and-video-example).

**My Approch was like bellow:**

```
child: TeXView(
  child: TeXViewDocument("""<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2No_CMrxBe8" style="width: 100vw; height: calc(100vw/1.77);" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"></iframe></div>""",
      style: TeXViewStyle(
        textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.Justify,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[50].withOpacity(.8),
      )),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will try to [EasyWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) plugin in a flutter web.

```
 Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: myColor.white,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: EasyWebView(
          src: widget.url,
          isHtml: false, // Use Html syntax
          isMarkdown: false, // Use markdown syntax
          onLoaded: () {  }, // Try to convert to flutter widgets
        ),
    ),
```